# setting css - content as empty string changes the background

Tags: css, background-color

I display the post titles which is an unordered list in my title bar. Css for header is set as,

```
.header{
    background: #f0f0f0;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px -2px #777;
    *zoom: 1;
    width: auto;
}
.header:before, .header:after {
    display: table; 
}
.header:after {
    clear: both; 
}
```

But the background color (or) shadow box is not displayed with the above properties. It comes with white bg color like this,

[image]

Then i added an extra property as

```
.header:before, .header:after {
  content: '';
}
```

The background color got applied as (i desired),
[image]

How does setting content as empty string before/after affect the background color of the header?

Comment: Yeah, `::before`s and `::after`s don't really do anything if they don't have a content. So giving them a content, even if it's empty, makes them work. Now the question becomes: why didn't the header have a background? Well, did it have any non-floating and non-absolute content? If it didn't, then it counted as empty and wouldn't have been drawn.

Comment: hi Lister, thanks for your comment... how does setting `content` property give the desired background `color`. Why does `background: #f0f0f0;` alone fail to do that? and i am using reactjs which loads the header items from a javascript list object...

Comment: Like I said, if an element does not have any content, it does not get drawn. The header only gets drawn if there's something in it! And if the things inside are all floating, or positioned absolutely, they don't count as "something"! So only the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements count, at least if they are in working order.

Comment: The default value for the `content:` property is `normal` which computes to `none` which means that "The pseudo-element is not generated".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sudo-elements `:before` and `:after` are nothing without `content`, these element are visible in page iff they have `content` and are hidden otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You can set all the properties you want to the pseudo elements before and after, but they won't occupy space without the attribute 'content' being set. And sorry for not commenting but i still don't have enough rep.